# create/change with sql <select> in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, html, sql

I have users table and i want the manageer will be able to select from  a user he wants to change/delete. How can I embed into the html code this sql query. Needless to say that in the .cs i need to start with

```
public string user = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string sql;
sql="SELECT 'usrname' FROM 'Users'";
user = MyAdoHelper.printDataTable("Database.mdf", sqlq);
}
```

but how can i convert user to a list?
thanks.

Comment: you need a third party to link your html and sql

Comment: Look into databound controls e.g. GridView. Check SqlDataSource, ObjectDataSource and their automatic insert/update/delete features

Comment: Can you please give example of how can i applicate it via GridView? thanks again.